# Javascript Coding in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, registration, email-validation

For an assignment I have I am writing a registration form. My question is how would I connect the first statement, and the function below so when someone types in their email in the text box it checks to see if the email is valid? (document.getElementById('user').value)

```
<input id="user" type="text" onblur="isUserNameValid();"></input><br/>


function isEmailValid(email) {
"use strict";
        var e = email.split("@"), local = /[^\w.!#$%&*+-\/=?^_{|}~]/, domain = /[\w.-]/;
if (e.length !== 2) {
    return false;
}
if (local.test(e[0])) {
    return false;
}
if (e[0].length > 253) {
    return false;
}
if ((e[0][0] === ".") || (/\.\./.test(e[0]))) {
    return false;
}
if (domain.test(e[1])) {
    return false;
}
if (e[1].length > 253) {
    return false;
}
if (e[1][0] === "." || /\.\./.test(e[1]) || e[1][e[1].length - 1] === ".") {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: You say assignment, can you use HTML5? Then you could simply set the input type to "email".

Comment: @Endophage Yes you can use HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

As you confirmed you can use HTML5, simply change your input to the below and the browser will validate the email for you when the form is submitted.

```
<input id="user" name="user" type="email" /><br/>
```

N.B. You can use a self closing tag for an input. You should also assign the `name` attribute of the `input` as that is what is used as the key for the data when it is submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email"  onblur="javascript:return validate();"/>

<script>
    function validate() {

        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        var address = document.getElementById("email").value;
        if (reg.test(address) == false) {

            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('valid Email Address');
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```